# Python sockets - send variable back to client from server

Tags: python, multithreading, sockets

I am using sockets for a client / server application, where I need to send a variable from the server back to the client when the use clicks a button, for example. I am using wxpython.

Here is a sample of my server code:

```
def handler(self, clientsocket, clientaddr):
    data22 = clientsocket.recv(1024)
    while 1:
        msg = "Message to send"
        clientsocket.sendall(msg)
    clientsocket.close()

def listen(self):
    host = ''
    port = 55567
    buf = 1024
    addr = (host, port)
    self.serversocket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM)
    self.serversocket.bind(addr)
    self.serversocket.listen(2)
    while 1:
        if self.canExit:
            print "trying to break"
            break
        print "Server is listening for connections\n"     
        clientsocket, clientaddr = self.serversocket.accept()
        threading.Thread(target=self.handler, args=(clientsocket, clientaddr)).start()
    print "closing the socket"
    self.serversocket.close()
```

And here is a sample of my client code:

```
def SendFolder(self):
    HOST = host=self.params["databaseLocation"]    # The remote host
    port = 55567
    buf = 1024
    addr = (host, port)
    clientsocket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM)
    clientsocket.connect(addr)
    if self.abortThisJob != False:
        clientsocket.sendall(self.abortThisJob)
    else:
        clientsocket.sendall("Send Job")

    self.listenThread = threading.Thread(target=self.listen, args=(clientsocket, buf))
    self.listenThread.daemon= True
    self.listenThread.start()

def listen(self, clientsocket, buf):
    while 1:
        data = raw_input(">> ")
        clientsocket.send(data)
        data = clientsocket.recv(buf)
        print data
```

Comment: Is there a question?

Comment: I don't know what your question is, but I doubt you want to close the client socket right after starting the `listen` function.

Comment: The question is: How would I send a message back to the client from the server, via a button press, for example? I updated the question also.